# Test runner that displays code coverage inline (FLOSS alternative to wallabyjs)

Tags: gratis, open-source, software-development, software-testing

I am looking for a continuous test runner that displays code coverage inline, integrated with editors and updated in pseudo real-time.

[wallayjs](https://wallabyjs.com/) is the best fully integrated example I can find and is impressive but proprietary (and quite expensive to outfit a large team).

Support for TypeScript, Mocha, Atom, and VSCode is needed. Solution can comprise of multiple alternatives but should be [FLOSS](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/floss-and-foss.en.html).

Comment: If you want coverage to be shown dynamically, please state it, thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for open-source, free-of-cost, or both?

Comment: There is no free lunch and 'libre' is key. The original title started with 'libre'.

Comment: @Tom - Libre can be read as free as in Open Source or as Gratis - please clarify. For the moment I have added tags for both.

Comment: @Steve-Barnes Libre explicitly means free as in freedom. Gratis is free as in free lunch.  Proprietary Software can have "open source" that allows me to look and maybe integrate but not transform and redistribute, thus not libre.  By using 'libre'  I was trying to be more exact but it seems I have been more confusing. I will add FLOSS to the question.

Comment: @Tom Did you find an alternative for wallabyjs? As indeed it's quite expensive...